# SonarQube and Java plugin installed, no rules under Quality Profiles

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-analysis, static-analysis, sonar-runner

I have installed SonarQube 3.7.3 and all of the relevant Java plugins for it.

Under the "Quality Profiles" tab, i cannot find any configured rules out of the box (except Android Lint):

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Should the system/plugin come with rules out of the box, or should i import them manually?

I have gone over the documentation a few times and didn't find any proper answer.

Answer (score 7):

See detail explanations and associated workaround http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4642#comment-335103

Comment: That bug is marked to be fixed in 4.1. I am currently running 3.7.3, is there any newer version that what i'm using ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve? The "Sonar way" Profile runs some fair analytics on my Android Projects providing informations according to coding styles and complexity as you can see in this article http://www.professional-android-development.com/articles/code-analysis-with-sonarqube-in-android-projects .  I am using Sonarqube 4.0. and I also see only this three qualitiy profiles listed, but they are doing their job.

Comment: Besides: I recently stumbled over this project https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android though haven't evaluated it yet it seems very interesting when it comes to automated testing and CI under Android.

Comment: It provides integration of several test frameworks for android in sonarqube.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a standard bug in the system. SonarQube have raised a internal defect resolution request to resolve the same.

There is a work around this.

Steps:

1. Create a new instance in some other locatioon by unzipping a fresh
   copy of sonarQube
2. Install Plugin on that new instance
3. Now take backup of the default quality profile
4. On old instance, Uninstall that plugin(if installed)
5. Import the backed up Quality profile into old new instance(make sure
   that plugin is not installed at this moment)
6. Now Install the plugin on old instance
7. Click on restore default profile

With above steps, you should get back the default rules for the built in plugins
Let me know if this helps

http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-4642#comment-335103

Best,Karthik